# why would this text is stored as empty in a text mysql field

Tags: php, mysql, string, rss, file-get-contents

```
%3Cimg+src%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fmnmstatic.net%2Fcache%2F15%2F15%2Fthumb-1381820.jpg%27+width%3D%2760%27+height%3D%2760%27+alt%3D%27%27+class%3D%27thumbnail%27+style%3D%27float%3Aright%3Bmargin-left%3A+3px%27+align%3D%27right%27+hspace%3D%273%27%2F%3E%3Cp%3EAunque+se+haya+dado+marcha+atr%C3%A1s%2C+lo+que+ha+ocurrido+en+RTVE+es+muy+serio.+Seg%C3%BAn+Gabilondo%2C+este+asunto+nos+permite+ver+con+claridad+por+d%C3%B3nde+va+la+pol%C3%ADtica+y+por+d%C3%B3nde+va+el+pensamiento+del+PP+entorno+a+la+libertad+de+informaci%C3%B3n.%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cstrong%3Eetiquetas%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3A+tve%2C+i%C3%B1aki+gabilondo%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%3Ca+href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fmenea.me%2Ftm7w%22%3E%3Cimg+src%3D%22http%3A%2F
%2Fwww.meneame.net%2Fbackend%2Fvote_com_img.php%3Fid%3D1381820%22+alt%3D%22votes%22+width
%3D%22200%22+height%3D%2216%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%26%23187%3B%26nbsp%3B%3Ca+href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.cadenaser.com%2Fla-voz-de-inaki%2F2011%2F09%2F23%2Ftve-acorralada%2F%22+onmousedown%3D%22this.href%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.meneame.net%2Fbackend%2Fgo.php%3Fid%3D1381820%27%3B+return+true%22+%3Enoticia+original%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fp%3E
```

This would be the text containded of a RSS file `$item->description` wich I'm trying to store in my MySQL database, but it stores an empty string.

This sample of text is been under an `echo` right before the `$mysql` query.

Is it because its preceded by `%3C`?

The full script would be:

```
$filename = "http://www.ofertasybonos.com/blog/?feed=rss2";
$feed = simplexml_load_file($filename);

//  Iterate through the list and create the unordered list
$n = false;
foreach ($feed->channel->item as $item) {
            $user       = "ofertasybonos";
            $pass       = "ofertasybono";
            $title = urlencode($item->title);
            if(strlen($item->description)>6000){
     $notes = urlencode(substr($item->description, 6000).'..' );
}else{
     $notes = urlencode($item->description);
}
            $url = urlencode($item->link);
            $tags = ''; $tags .= urlencode(urlencode($item->category)); if($tags=='')  $tags = urlencode("ofertas, bonos");

            $params = "nombre=$user&pass=$pass&url=$url&tags=$tags&notes=$notes&title=$title";

            $res = file_get_contents ("http://domain.com/API/public/autosave.php?$params");
            /*this file getContents stores in database*/


    $n = true;
}


this is how is (supoused to be) stored
```

Recive data form file_get_contents

```
$texto = urldecode($_GET['notes']);
```

Store in database

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO links (nombre, coment, url, iduser,fecha,priv)
                               VALUES ('$b','$r_int','$texto ','$id_tmp',NOW(),'$priv')";
```

Any idea why the text is stored empty?

Comment: Where's the code where you store and retrieve that string?

Comment: Since you've verified that the string is correct, the problem is probably in how you're storing it in the database, so you should include the MySQL code in your question.

Comment: `%3C` is `<`, which does not have any special meaning in MySQL.  The `%` does have a special meaning, it's a wildcard And I think it needs to be escaped with a `\` like so: `'\%3C.....` for each '%'.

Comment: You didn't include the code that actually stores the data in the DB, include that as well.

Comment: $_GET, mysql_real_escape and the insert. It was allways like this; used to work. what i'm sure it changed its the RSS content

Comment: @johan so what str_replace you suggest? thanks

Comment: I would really like to see the actual code, the devil is in the details.

Comment: updated with code you wanted :D

Comment: since it is being decoded, what happens when you echo $texto? is it inserting the note into the right field?

Comment: interesting. server changed and it's working again

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is the correct solution, but if you try serialize the data ?

Method to serialize your data is serialize(); http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php
Method to unserialize your data is unserialize(); http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 0):

You forgot $ in front of of texto

`$insert = "INSERT INTO links (nombre, coment, url, iduser,fecha,priv)
                               VALUES ('$b','$r_int','$texto','$id_tmp',NOW(),'$priv')";`

Comment: aha.. true, but its only in the question in my .php file is fine, edited: thanks & sorry